# i am coding for matrix multiplication and addition and i got this error 'TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable'. all answers are appreciated :)

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

```
print("enter n for nxn matrix:")
n = int(input())

matrix1 = []
matrix2 = []

# elements of first matrix

print("enter elements of first matrix:")
for i in range(0, n):
    # elements of first column

    print("enter elements of {} column".format(i))

    # the elements will be separated by a space
    # input().split() will split the string
    # '1 23 456'.split() will give ['1', '23', '456']
    # map will convert its elements into integers [1, 23, 456]

    matrix1.append(map(int,input().split()))

print("Matrix 1 is {}".format(matrix1))

# taking elements of second matrix

print("enter elements of second matrix")
for i in range(0, n):
    print("enter elements of {} column".format(i))
    matrix2.append(map(int,input().split()))

print("Matrix 2 is {}".format(matrix2))

# addition

addition = []
for i in range(0, n):
    a = []
    for j in range(0, n):
        # making a addition matrix's column to append
        # making a 1D matrix with elements as sum of elements of respective columns of both matrices

        a.append(matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j])
    addition.append(a)
print("Addition of matrix is {}".format(addition))

# multiplication
multiplication = []
for i in range(0, n):
    a = []
    for j in range(0, n):
        b = 0
        for k in range(0, n):
            b = b + (matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j])
        a.append(b)
    multiplication.append(a)
print("Multiplication of matrix is {}".format(multiplication))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `map` function it return you the map object

```
map(int,"3".split())
<map at 0x7f3550af16d8>
```

If you want to push the list you should call it for example:

```
list(map(int,"3".split()))
[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

In *Python **3***, [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Functions - map(function, iterable, ...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator. You should convert it to a list in order to add it as a row in your matrix, or better: use the (newer and cleaner) list comprehension:

> ```py
> >>> m = map(int, input().split())
> 1 2 34
> >>> m
> <map object at 0x000001F4EC5B3250>
> >>> list(m)
> [1, 2, 34]
> >>>
> >>> lc = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
> 1 2 34
> >>> lc
> [1, 2, 34]
> ```